# Not getting daily updates of answers

Tags: support, email-notification

I've specified my email and it says it's already registered for receiving daily updates to answers received but I never get emails.  Checked my spam box / filter also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not receiving notifications on new answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5673/not-receiving-notifications-on-new-answers)

Comment: @Jon: That question is over a year old, so it's possible a new bug is in the system.

Comment: @Jon: I wonder who I'm talking to?

Comment: @mmy: To Jon! No, honestly to Seigel. Always the last one in the queue ...

Comment: @Jon: What makes you think, that something was changed the last time? Please say the status-tag, so I can laugh at you.

Comment: @mmyers: That one hit me, and I'm pretty sure it *didn't* hit Jon B. Unless the reply system has been changed recently.

Comment: @Ladybug: Errrrr... I suppose I should have read the question in its entirety. I still agree with TheTXI's answer, though. Voting to close. Would you like to do the honours and roll back the `[status-completed]` tag? :)

Comment: @Jon: Lovely idea :) Done!

Comment: I don't think this feature has ever worked for me.  And I know because it already told me that email was registered and I have NEVER gotten emails even months and months ago.  I just decided today that I had enough and wanted to put this bug in.

Comment: @cof: It is widely guessed, that you do not get emails, if you have already looked at the answers (e.g. via the envelope icon). Probably email only works, if you do not visit SO at all. Otherwise the system thinks you already know the new stuff.

Comment: I do not assume that.  That's a usabilty issue then because most forums email you when you subscribe.  This feature needs to be improved to be more underderstandble and more usable.   It's useless if I have no clue how the thing works...especially when the pattern of subscribing to a thread in all other forums on the net works the same...and even if I did not view the answers I'm STILL not getting emails.  So either way it's a bug AND a usability issue..2 issues actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:

your account has no email address in it, so therefore we cannot possibly email you.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/93468/coffeeaddict

If you want emails, enter an email address.

edit: ah, I see you have a duplicate registered account, with an email, from Feb 9 2009 at

https://stackoverflow.com/users/62759

I have merged that into your main account.

Comment: /me opens `[feature-request]` for automatic email prediction :)

Comment: Ok, wtf.  Then why when I put my email into the subscribe box, it tells it's already registered?  Go figure right?  Jeff this is a usability issue, major.  Of all the other features in this forum, this is the only issue I have.  If you've got a textbox asking for an email and then a) says it's already registered  and b) there's not even an indication that it's been saved in that textbox and c) you're expected to manually go into your account to specify that same email then what's the point of this feature at all if it doesn't work intuitively?  I guarantee it's not intuitive to all.

Comment: also I'm using openID, so one would assume if you put in an email to the subscribe box that Stackoverflow is albe to at least save that for you??  I don't get it.

Comment: "/me opens [feature-request] for automatic email prediction :) ".  I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Just went to my account using the edit option.  I see an email right there!  So not sure what you're talking about Jeff??